# Compare a (single small list) with a (list of lists) in python

Tags: python, list

I am working with python 3.6. I have a list `coordinates = [101758584, 101837149, 101844851]` and another list of lists `rows = [['1', '36933096', 'CSF3R', 'chr1:g.36933096T>C', 'Pathogenic', 'Tarceva\n'], ['2', '25463483', 'DNMT3A', 'chr2:g.25463483G>A', 'Pathogenic', 'Tarceva\n'], ['2', '25469502', 'DNMT3A', 'chr2:g.25469502C>T', 'risk factor', 'Iressa\n']].... and this list goes on`. I want to check if the numbers present in coordinates are present in the rows list.
So far what I have tried is -

```
coordinates = [101758584, 101837149, 101844851]
rows = [['1', '36933096', 'CSF3R', 'chr1:g.36933096T>C', 'Pathogenic', 'Tarceva\n'], ['2', '25463483', 'DNMT3A', 'chr2:g.25463483G>A', 'Pathogenic', 'Tarceva\n'], ['2', '25469502', 'DNMT3A', 'chr2:g.25469502C>T', 'risk factor', 'Iressa\n']]
    for e in rows:
            if e[0] in coordinates:
                chromo_final.append(e)

        print(chromo_final)
```

The output for this is an empty list.
The second thing that I tried was -

```
chromo_final=[x for x in rows if x[0] in coordinates]
print(chromo_final)
```

Even this code gives an empty list.
One example of the output is -

```
7   101755060   CUX1    chr7:g.101755060A>G Likely pathogenic   Cotellic
```

The pattern in the coordinates is present on the second position of the output.
This output can be of many lines as my list of lists is huge.
I would love to know so as to exactly where I am going wrong and also how can I go about this code to get the correct output.

Comment: Have you tried using any of the biopython modules?

Comment: @K.Land_bioinfo : I couldn't use any of the modules and neither of my associates can, therefore, I needed a more generic way to perform the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is to use `list comprehension`, One thing to point out is data types of `coordinates` and `rows[1]` are different, and also your coordinate is at `index-1` so instead of `x[0]` use `x[1]`

```
>>> [i for i in rows for j in coordinates if i[1] == str(j)]
```

Comment: Perfect! Big Thank you!

Comment: @Srk Glad to hear that, if this is correct answer please mark it as correct for future users